# android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON event fires twice if i press Headset button once

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have written a code to show `Toast` when the headset media button is pressed.I used intent filter to do it. But the problem is when i press the media button it fires twice.
My Code is:

**MainActivity.java**

```
private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myReceiver=new MusicIntentReceiver();

    ((AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(
            this,
            MusicIntentReceiver.class));
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    IntentFilter filter1=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    filter1.setPriority(100);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver,filter1);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    IntentFilter filter1=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    filter1.setPriority(100);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver,filter1);
    super.onPause();
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction=intent.getAction();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Action: "+intentAction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once for button down, once for button up.

```
  KeyEvent keyEvent  = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
  if (keyEvent != null) {
      if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
      {
           switch(keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                  .... &c.
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: yeah i figured that out for button press and release